# Will MapBox supports for Indoor Navigation implementation in Xamarin.Forms (Android/IOS/UWP)?

Tags: xamarin.forms, mapbox, mapbox-android, indoor-positioning-system, mapbox-ios

I just started checking for **MapBox**. I could not find any information about **Indoor Navigation Implementation** with the following requirements:

1. IPS (Indoor Positioning System by displaying "Blue dot" for accuracy)
2. Showing POI's
3. Static / Dynamic Navigation between two points (using any REST API's)

**Can someone let me know first whether MapBox supports Xamarin.Forms for Indoor Navigation implementation?**